# Reflink copy diff

Tags: cp, btrfs, diff, reflink

I want to make a behaviour like `btrfs send` and `btrfs receive`, but on a per-file basis.
As far as I see it, I can use `cp -ax --reflink=always` to make a "snapshot" of the file.
Let's assume that two such "snapshots" on two different hard disks are exactly equal.
How do I `cp` the diff (and only the diff) between two reflinked files like `btrfs send -p` would do it?

Ideally, I would like to have a solution that works on any filesystem that is capable of making reflinks and not only on btrfs. Also ideally, I would like to run it without sudo.

I know that I can look at the file extents with `filefrag`, but `filefrag` does not guarantee that the results are exact. I would rather copy some megabytes more than taking the risk of a corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround (not tested yet):

1. Create a new subvolume X and a subvolume Y on the original disk.
2. Use `cp -ax --reflink=always` to copy the old version to subvolume X and the new one to subvolume Y.
3. Copy subvolume X to the second disk using `btrfs send` (if this is the first time you are doing this) or re-create subvolume X from the file as in step 1 and 2 (if not).
4. Copy subvolume Y to the second disk using `btrfs send -p`.
5. Reflink the file inside subvolume Y on the second disk accordingly (replacing the old file) and delete all subvolumes used in the process.

Warning: I'm not sure if this works at all. I'll need extensive testing to ensure that this really does what it should do. In theory, if the creation of subvolumes is 100% reproducible (=performing the same operations twice results in an equivalent internal state of the btrfs tree), it should work.

I would still be happy for a proper solution.

---

**Edit:** You can of cause check if `filefrag` produces the same result on both disks.